# What does Request 1 mean in Soap's REST Request?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a SOAP UI question and wanted clarification on something. When I select a particular REST request, it displays two options for each request

- Api -> CRUD method -> Request Name
- Api -> CRUD method -> Request Name-> Request 1

My question is what is the difference between Request 1 and those that don't display Request 1 for each one?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried? what did you notice?

Comment: I tried a while ago but it looked the same, I'll have another look

Comment: I see no difference, It's just been that I've been asked this and I don't know difference between the two (if there is any) I just tell people to use the one without request 1

Answer (score 3):

Request 1 is just a **default** request which gets created in SoapUI when u add a new REST Service from URI.
[See Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry56A.png)

You can delete this Request or Add new ones.
1. If you delete this it will not appear in the dropdown.
2. If you add one more request say Request 2 then Request 1,Request 2 both will appear in the dropdown.
The purpose might be to have generic settings at one place so that you can clone it whenever you need it in further testsuites or testcases.